# Grouping Checkboxes - jQuery / JS / ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

So I am grouping the checkboxes with data-groupname and use jQuery to auto-select the whole group if one of the group member is checked.

Here's my JS code:

```
function checkAllList(listNavPath, selectAllId, checkBoxes) {

if (!checkBoxes) {
    checkBoxes = $(listNavPath + ":not(#" + selectAllId + ")")
}; //Exclude first checkbox

function selectAllCheckBoxes() {
    if (checkBoxes.filter(":checked").length == checkBoxes.length) {
        $("#" + selectAllId).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#" + selectAllId).prop("checked", false);
    }
}
selectAllCheckBoxes();

$(document).on("click", "#" + selectAllId, function () { checkBoxes.prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); });
$(document).on("click", checkBoxes, function (e) {
        var isChecked = $(e.target).prop("checked");
        var parent = $(e.target).parent();
        var groupName = $(parent).data("groupname");     
        var chs = $("[data-groupname='" + groupName + "']");

        $(chs).each(function (i) {           
            var chk = $(chs[i]).children().first();

            $(chk).prop('checked', isChecked);           
        })
```

This works just fine but I want to limit the .each() to only loop thru the parent of "group name parent" if that makes sense. In other words, I don't want to look for any group-names outside of that table. In my example is looking on the whole page to find the that group name and then if "Parent Group Name" == "groupName" then auto-select / deselect the group or else return true; to continue the loop.

This is my checkbox the ASP markup. What this does, is creating a column of checkboxes, one per each row. The checkboxes are generated dynamically from the code behind (vb.net).

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderTemplate><asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="true" /></HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate><asp:CheckBox runat="server" data-groupname='<%#Eval("InvoiceCreditNumber")%>' Checked="true" ID="chkSelected" /></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Looking forward for any ideas of what approach to take in order to make this work.

Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear how the markup is finally rendered. You can restrict the selector in `var chs = $(...)` or use context for the constructor. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

This is what I did in order to make it work:

I got the table like this:

```
var tblID = $(e.target).closest('.select-all');
```

because `.select-all` is a class that I'm using for all the tables where I use checkboxes.

and then I only loop within that table like this:

```
 var chs = $(tblID).find("[data-groupname='" + groupName + "']")
        $(chs).each(function (i) {           
        var chk = $(chs[i]).children().first();         
        $(chk).prop('checked', isChecked);           
    })
```

Thanks everyone for your responses. You are all upvoted.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, I don't want to look for any group-names outside of that **table**.

If that table has an ID or a class, you can limit the selection of "[data-groupname='" + groupName + "'] to the table, like this:

**$("[data-groupname='" + groupName + "']", "#id-table")**;

or

**$("#id-table").find("[data-groupname='" + groupName + "']")**;

Comment: Thanks Loris. That's good to know. Thing is I want something more generic / dynamic without specifying the table id but by checking somehow it's parents.

Comment: I tried this: **$(this).closest('table').attr('id')** but for some reason I can't make it work.

Comment: With .attr("id") you take the ID of the table. If you want to take all the groupname inside the table using closest and no id, try this: $(this).closest('table').find("[data-groupname='" + groupName + "']") or _$("[data-groupname='" + groupName + "']", "table")_ (i dont reccommend this, because it could be too generic in some situations).